# Will it cause problems if I publish under a different version of my name than I use in my future medical practice?

Tags: publications, personal-name, medicine

I'm a medical student who is also interested in research and scientific publishing.

Although my legal name is Asian, I go by an English name with peers and supervisors (which is not on my degrees/official school records). In the future, I will have to use just my Asian first name when I practice medicine (but this won't matter because I will just be Dr.LastName anyways).

I'm just wondering what I should be publishing under - I found that a lot of people on pubmed/GScholar share my Asian name...and with my supervisors I am known by **EnglishName-AsianName LastName**.

Will publishing under this hyphenated name pose future problems if I practice just under AsianName?

I'm thinking problems such as not being recognized in research communities, hospital affiliations with research-based hospitals, etc.

Comment: Have you published any paper yet?

Comment: @scaaahu Moved discussion on applicability of [tag:asia] tag [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20050/discussion-between-ff524-and-scaaahu) to avoid an extended discussion here.

Comment: And also, are you in Asia currently?

Comment: Why not use a variation of.middle names: Wendy Weiwei KANG or Weiwei Wendy Lang.

Comment: @ff524 - I'm thinking problems such as not being recognized in research communities, hospital affiliations with research-based hospitals, etc.

Comment: I added that info to the post, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @scaaahu - I'm currently in Canada

Comment: @ff524 - thank you for your help! It's my first time on this forum

Comment: Medical researchers are unfortunately underrepresented here (there's a [poll](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/470/11365), if you're inserted). We're very happy you're here, and I hope you stick around :)

Comment: I'd love to stick around - everyone here has been so helpful! Will vote as soon as I have enough reputation points!

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt it will cause you any problems in future.

A lot of people would change their family name as a result of marriage and even that not too terrible.

Comment: Mh, I figure that as long as I compile all my papers on my CV/research profile website, it doesn't really matter if my publication has a different first name initial...as long as I don't publish with someone else with my last name haha

Comment: *Um,* if your last name is "Kim" or "Wang" (or "Brown") you have some competition.